# Android StackOverflow error on enabling MultiDex

Tags: android, stack-overflow, android-multidex

I'm getting the following exception after enabling MultiDex. My custom Application class is as follows.

```
public class PFApplication extends SugarApp {
   @Override
   public void onCreate() {
       super.onCreate();
       Branch.getAutoInstance(this);
   }

   @Override
   protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
       super.attachBaseContext(this);
       MultiDex.install(this);
   }

}
```

And given below is the stacktrace. App crashes on launch.

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                   Process: com.riverviewcs.product.friend, PID: 26404
>                                                                                   java.lang.StackOverflowError
>                                                                                       at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageManager(ContextWrapper.java:100)
>                                                                                                                                                                    ......

Any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this error

> java.lang.StackOverflowError at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageManager

**[StackOverflowError](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/StackOverflowError.html)**

**Thrown when a stack overflow occurs because an application recurses too deeply.**

You should rectify your `attachBaseContext` section .

**FYI**

Call `base` instead of `this`

```
super.attachBaseContext(base);
```

Comment: @KasunDelgolla Move ahead